# Dynamic Mapping changes

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

When there is any change in DDL of any table,  we have to again import source and target definition and change mapping. Is there a way to dynamically fetch the DDL of the table and do the data copy using Informatica mapping.

Comment: No, I think it not possible as of now. However even if you can import the tables automatically, you have to connect new columns or change port datatypes in your mapping manually.

Answer (score 0):

The ETL uses an abstractive layer, separated from any physical database. It uses Source and Target definition that indicate what should be expected to find in DB to which the job will be connecting. Keep in mind that the same data mapping can be applied to many different source and / or target systems. It's not bound to any of them, it just defines what data to fetch and what to do with them.

In Informatica this is reflected by separating Mappings, that define data flow, and Sessions, which indicate where the logic should be applied.

Imagine you're transferring data from multiple servers. A change applied on one of them should not break the whole data integration. If the changes would be dynamically reflected, then a column added on one server would make it impossible to read data from the others.

Of course if perfectly fine to have such requirement as you've mentioned. It's just not something Informatica supports with their approach.

The only way workaround is to create your own application that would fetch table definitions, generate the Workflows and import them into Informatica prior to execution.